# PHP + mysqli: push array into array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I basically need to create an array like this: http://pastebin.com/BAfRnTLz

I have two different tables in my db. One for projects and one for tasks. Each task has a column for the project id it belongs to. I need to create a multidimensional array where I look at each tasks ID in relation to the projects id, and append that task to the array of the correct project.

I fear i i'm going in the wrong direction. I have been trying to make this work for two days now (very new at this). Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

I have this so far

```
$projects = $mysqli->query("SELECT projectID, projectName FROM projects WHERE userID = '".$userID."'");
while (($row = $projects->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
print_r($row);

$projectID = $row['projectID'];
$tasks = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE projectID = '".$projectID."'");
while (($row = $tasks->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Please paste your sample code directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin.  The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions.  Therefore, future readers will probably not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Answer (score 0):

A join would be better suited for this but you could bolt them together like this assuming you don't have a field called `tasks` in projects.

```
$p = array();

$projects = $mysqli->query("SELECT projectID, projectName FROM projects WHERE userID = '".$userID."'");
while (($row = $projects->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
    $p[$row['projectID']] = $row;
}

$projectID = $row['projectID'];
$tasks = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE projectID = '".$projectID."'");
while (($row = $tasks->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
    $p[$row['projectID']]['tasks'][] = $row;
}

print_r($p);
```

Comment: Thanks! So I got that working (had to place the $tasks inside the while loop for $projects though), but how can I make that array look like http://pastebin.com/BAfRnTLz ?